# Android Memory leak (Activity) how to find the cause

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks

So I am the process of finding out why one of my activities is being reported as leaked.
So far i just cannot find the root cause of the leak.
I made a snapshot of heap analyser

[image: analyser snapshot]

But i see nothing other than android components.
The way how my app works is that it first starts a loaderActivity
and just after a few seconds another activity is created (it does some config work inside the loaderActivity)
The code is:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loader);

    //set some values

    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();
```

}

Now is the report from the analyser tool just a false positive?
or do i really have a leak here?
And if yes how can i find out what the cause is?

Comment: Try https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure this is an issue, but my activity transitions follow this pattern and they don't leak (per Leak Canary)

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.cardflip_in, R.anim.cardflip_out);
finish();
```

It's worth a try.